# Can't connect my development environment to a newly imported postgres database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, migration

Someone sent me the sql files of a dump database. I imported it through the following command: `psql my_dbname < infile.sql`

I changed my database.yml file with the following:

```
development:
  <<: *default
  database: my_dbname
```

But when I run rails server, I don't have the expected data. Is there something I'm missing ? I think there are some stuff I need to do with roles but I'm not sure.

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you add block `default:` from database.yml?

Comment: Are you done with "rake db:create" and "rake db:migrate" before importing the .sql file

Comment: Read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What is `infile.sql`? What is your `default` config? What steps did you take to reach this point?

Comment: DaniilMaksimov what do you mean by adding the block ? @Navin, yes it's done. When re-run these commands, it says indeed that my_dbname already exists. But it says that the former exists to. When I try to rake db:drop, it says that I don't have the permission.

Comment: @TomLord, I inherited from a code base that had the development environment connected to a db that we'll call former_db. The data of that db comes from the seed file. But the seed file is not relevant enough, so we decided to use the data that are in production at a specific date (more data, still small enough not to be overwhelmed). These data are in the file infile.sql, that I imported as described above. This is where it all starts :)

Comment: Before `development:` key, you have `default:` key, that past into `development:` settings. Can you add the contents of  `default:` key?

Answer (score 0):

Are you done with `rake db:create` and `rake db:migrate` before importing the .sql file if not then do the following

```
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

and then import .sql file

```
psql my_dbname < infile.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
psql -d my_dbname -a -f infile.sql
```

Comment: If i already did the 3rd command you wrote, will there be any duplication issue ?

Comment: I think that the first time you insert a different database.